# How to append rather than replace INSERT values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a text file which holds data in it. It holds 3 columns worth of data per row, with each column being separated by a comma. I'm trying to create a database from this file, but only the last row is saving.

Sample file:

```
Something,More,7
Another,Thing,9
One,Extra,3
```

Script:

```
<?php
$myFile = file('data.txt');

    foreach ($myFile as $row){
        list($a,$b,$c) = explode(',', $row);
        $insertStmt = "INSERT INTO `MYTABLE` (`id`, `a`, `b`, `c`)" . PHP_EOL
                    . "  VALUES (NULL, '$a', '$b', $c);";
    }
?>
```

When I `` 'SELECT * FROM `MYTABLE`;' ``, only the last submitted values appear (`One Extra 3`). I want it to hold all of the data values in rows. I see documentation on using a combination of `SELECT * FROM` and `INSERT INTO` to append data, but I don't understand it and it seems to append a pre-existing table to a new one. I just want to update the current table with new values.

How would I append the new data onto the existing table rather than replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is looping through the file, and redefining the variable `$insertStmt` every single loop. That's counter productive, you need to append it on each loop instead. Something like this would work much better.

```
<?php
$myFile     = file('data.txt');
$insertStmt = "";
$i          = 0;


    foreach ($myFile as $row) {
        list($a,$b,$c) = explode(',', $row);

        if( $i == 0 )
            $insertStmt = $insertStmt . "INSERT INTO `MYTABLE` (`id`, `a`, `b`, `c`) VALUES ";
        else 
            $insertStmt = $insertStmt . "(NULL, '$a', '$b', $c),";

        $i++;
    }

        $insertStmt = rtrim($insertStmt, ",");
        $insertStmt = $insertStmt . ";"
?>
```